# Why is my regex exponentially slow with more operators in account?

Tags: regex, performance, perl

So I'm building a parser with perl regular expressions. I'm using code in the middle of the pattern to achieve precedence. I also have a build system that automatically generates "shadow" regexes that are called facets and don't contain any code so I can polyfill to a full match when I'm matching out of order.

Anyway right now I've created an example that is hand written and shows my code for binary operation matching. It gets exponentially slower, no-matter if the operators exists in the expression, the higher in the chain we go.

For example if I start with the shift operator it'll take like 1 sec but if I start with the and logical it would take like a whole minute or something (I've not measure the time but it's significantly slower) and as I've mentioned before the actual operators doesn't contain any of the higher precedence one - only the lowest in the chain - like addition and multiplication.

Here is the perl example (I'm coming from pcre2 where it outright fails when launched like this with exhausted match count):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$text = "7*7*4*5*6*7+(4*4*4+3*7*4);7*7*4*5*6*7+(4*4*4+3*7*4)";

$result = $text =~/((*F) (?# << clever way of declaring subroutines in a regex without actually executing them)

(?<orlogicplusrest>(?>(?&andlogicplusrest))(?>(?<orlogicop>(?<orlogicopraw>\|\|)(?>(?&orlogicplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&andlogicplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{orlogicopraw}\n")if($+{orlogicopraw});}))

(?<andlogicplusrest>(?>(?&orplusrest))(?>(?<andlogicop>(?<andlogicopraw>&&)(?>(?&andlogicplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&orplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{andlogicopraw}\n")if($+{andlogicopraw});}))

(?<orplusrest>(?>(?&xorplusrest))(?>(?<orop>(?!\|\|)(?<oropraw>\|)(?>(?&orplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&xorplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{oropraw}\n")if($+{oropraw});}))

(?<xorplusrest>(?>(?&andplusrest))(?>(?<xorop>(?<xoropraw>\^)(?>(?&xorplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&andplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{xoropraw}\n")if($+{xoropraw});}))

(?<andplusrest>(?>(?&eqplusrest))(?>(?<andop>(?!&&)(?<andopraw>&)(?>(?&andplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&eqplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{andopraw}\n")if($+{andopraw});}))

(?<eqplusrest>(?>(?&relplusrest))(?>(?<eqop>(?<eqopraw>==|!=)(?>(?&eqplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&relplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{eqopraw}\n")if($+{eqopraw});}))

(?<relplusrest>(?>(?&shiftplusrest))(?>(?<relop>(?<relopraw>(?!<<)<|(?!>>)>|<=|>=)(?>(?&relplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&shiftplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{relopraw}\n")if($+{relopraw});}))

(?<shiftplusrest>(?>(?&addmulplusrest))(?>(?<shiftop>(?<shiftopraw><<|>>)(?>(?&shiftplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&addmulplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{shiftopraw}\n")if($+{shiftopraw});}))

(?<addmulplusrest>(?>(?&muloprest))(?>(?<addop>(?!\+\+|--)(?<addopraw>[\+\-])(?>(?&addmulplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&muloprestfacet))(?{print("$+{addopraw}\n") if($+{addopraw});}))

(?<muloprest>(?>(?&testxpr))(?>(?<mulop>(?<mulopraw>[\*\/\%])(?>(?&muloprest))))
    |(?>(?&testxprfacet))(?{print("$+{mulopraw}\n") if($+{mulopraw});}))

(?# entry point - replace here)

(?<testentry>(?<innertest>(?>(?&orlogicplusrest)));(?&innertest);)

(?# either in parnetheses or without)

(?<testxpr>(?&inner)|(?&inparenths))

(?# testexpr facet - replace here)

(?<testxprfacet>(?&innerraw)|\s*[(](?&orlogicplusrestfacet)[)]\s*)

(?<inparenths>\s*[(](?&innertest)[)]\s*)


(?# a digit)

(?<inner>(?<innerraw>\d++)(?{print("$+{innerraw}\n") if($+{innerraw});}))


(?#following are facets - you can safely ignore them - they are the same as the above except they don't print anything)

(?<orlogicplusrestfacet>(?>(?&andlogicplusrestfacet))(?>((\|\|)(?>(?&orlogicplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&andlogicplusrestfacet)))

(?<andlogicplusrestfacet>(?>(?&orplusrestfacet))(?>((&&)(?>(?&andlogicplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&orplusrestfacet)))

(?<orplusrestfacet>(?>(?&xorplusrestfacet))(?>((?!\|\|)(\|)(?>(?&orplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&xorplusrestfacet)))

(?<xorplusrestfacet>(?>(?&andplusrestfacet))(?>((\^)(?>(?&xorplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&andplusrestfacet)))

(?<andplusrestfacet>(?>(?&eqplusrestfacet))(?>((?!&&)(&)(?>(?&andplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&eqplusrestfacet)))

(?<eqplusrestfacet>(?>(?&relplusrestfacet))(?>((==|!=)(?>(?&eqplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&relplusrestfacet)))

(?<relplusrestfacet>(?>(?&shiftplusrestfacet))(?>(((?!<<)<|(?!>>)>|<=|>=)(?>(?&relplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&shiftplusrestfacet)))

(?<shiftplusrestfacet>(?>(?&addmulplusrestfacet))(?>((<<|>>)(?>(?&shiftplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&addmulplusrestfacet)))

(?<addmulplusrestfacet>(?>(?&muloprestfacet))(?>((?!\+\+|--)([\+\-])(?>(?&addmulplusrestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&muloprestfacet)))

(?<muloprestfacet>(?>(?&testxprfacet))(?>(([\*\/\%])(?>(?&muloprestfacet))))
    |(?>(?&testxprfacet)))

(?#end facets - follows the entry point)

)|(^(?&testentry))/xx;
                        
                        
print $&;
```

On the places where it says replace here you can change the `orlogicplusrest` with any other operator in the chain to check performance - for example if you put the `shiftplusrest` (and `shiftplusrestfacet`) it will execute almost instantly.

So my question is - is there any way we can speed things up while accounting for every single operator in the right order. I've tried adding atomic groups everywhere but it's still the same.

Comment: At some point a single giant regular expression is not the best approach...

Comment: @Shawn That's why I've created my meta regex preprocessor but even then I've to write each binary operator in its own subroutine - but this is not such a huge drawback since they are numbered. However generally everything in it's own file and short. And facets are not written but auto-generated instead.

Comment: Did you try [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars) ?

Comment: Are you creating a caluculator or are you trying to parse some existing language or [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)?

Comment: Are you only interested in matching a math expression like `7*7*4*5*6*7+(4*4*4+3*7*4)` (determine if the expression matched or not) and not actually computing the value (=41308) of the expression?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I'm creating a C parser - i.e. a parser that can parse a C program - that's why I'm using code inside the regex - the idea is at certain points in it to spit out data that I can use to construct llvm byte code or just print it out in the right order.

Comment: Consider using [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2)

Comment: Re "*clever way of declaring subroutines*" No need for a hack: `(?(DEFINE)definitions...)`

Answer (score 1):

So actually in all honesty I had a solution in a prior version that is actually working - I only had to tweak it a bit.

I've no idea how it's doing it but it's faster and it's working. The only caveat is you need to specify where the expression terminates otherwise it'll shrink to the first operation.

Umh you can compare them basically in the one case - the original we have for example:

```
~/(?<orlogicplusrest>(?>(?&andlogicplusrest))(?>(?<orlogicop>(?<orlogicopraw>\|\|)(?>(?&orlogicplusrest))))
    |(?>(?&andlogicplusrestfacet))(?{print("$+{orlogicopraw}\n")if($+{orlogicopraw});}))/
```

As you can see here we match the whole thing - both right and left side but on the other hand in my faster solution here:

```
~/(?<orlogicplusrest>(?<orlogicop>(?<orlogicopraw>\|\|)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&andlogicplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{orlogicopraw}\n")if($+{orlogicopraw});}))|(?&andlogicplusrest)(?&orlogicop)?)/
```

Is only matching as a postfix to something and it's used in the `primexprnoternary` to craft the cycle:

```
~/(?<primexprnoternary>(?&testxpr)((?&orlogicplusrest)?+)*?)/
```

As `primexprnoternary` is also used on the right side inside the operator.

In the other solution we just write:

```
~/(?<innertest>(?>(?&orlogicplusrest)))/
```

Here is the full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$text = "7*7*4*5*6*7+(4*4*4+3*7*4);";

$result = $text =~/((*F) (?# << clever way of declaring subroutines in a regex without actually executing them)


(?<orlogicplusrest>(?<orlogicop>(?<orlogicopraw>\|\|)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&andlogicplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{orlogicopraw}\n")if($+{orlogicopraw});}))|(?&andlogicplusrest)(?&orlogicop)?)

(?<andlogicplusrest>(?<andlogicop>(?<andlogicopraw>&&)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&orplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{andlogicopraw}\n")if($+{andlogicopraw});}))|(?&orplusrest)(?&andlogicop)?)

(?<orplusrest>(?<orop>(?!\|\|)(?<oropraw>\|)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&xorplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{oropraw}\n")if($+{oropraw});}))|(?&xorplusrest)(?&orop)?)

(?<xorplusrest>(?<xorop>(?<xoropraw>\^)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&andplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{xoropraw}\n")if($+{xoropraw});}))|(?&andplusrest)(?&xorop)?)

(?<andplusrest>(?<andop>(?!&&)(?<andopraw>&)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&eqplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{andopraw}\n")if($+{andopraw});}))|(?&eqplusrest)(?&andop)?)

(?<eqplusrest>(?<eqop>(?<eqopraw>==|!=)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&relplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{eqopraw}\n")if($+{eqopraw});}))|(?&relplusrest)(?&eqop)?)

(?<relplusrest>(?<relop>(?<relopraw>(?!<<)<|(?!>>)>|<=|>=)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&shiftplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{relopraw}\n")if($+{relopraw});}))|(?&shiftplusrest)(?&relop)?)

(?<shiftplusrest>(?<shiftop>(?<shiftopraw><<|>>)(?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&addmulplusrestfacet))
    (?{print("$+{shiftopraw}\n")if($+{shiftopraw});}))|(?&addmulplusrest)(?&shiftop)?)
    
(?<addmulplusrest>(?<addop>(?<addopraw>[\+\-])((?&primexprnoternary)(?!(?&mulopfacet))
    (?{print("$+{addopraw}\n")if($+{addopraw});})))|(?&mulop)(?&addop)?)

(?<mulop>(?<mulopraw>[\*\/\%])(?&primexprnoternary)
    (?{print("$+{mulopraw}\n")if($+{mulopraw});}))

(?# entry point)

(?<testentry>(?<innertest>(?&primexprnoternary));)

(?# replace here)

(?<primexprnoternary>(?&testxpr)((?&orlogicplusrest)?+)*?)

(?# either in parnetheses or without)

(?<testxpr>(?&inner)|(?&inparenths))

(?# primexprnoternary facet - replace here)

(?<primexprnoternaryfacet>(?&testxprfacet)((?&orlogicplusrestfacet)?+)*?)

(?<testxprfacet>(?&innerraw)|\s*[(](?&primexprnoternaryfacet)[)]\s*)

(?<inparenths>\s*[(](?&primexprnoternary)[)]\s*)


(?# a digit)

(?<inner>(?<innerraw>\d++)(?{print("$+{innerraw}\n") if($+{innerraw});}))


(?#following are facets - you can safely ignore them - they are the same as the above except they don't print anything)

(?<orlogicplusrestfacet>(?&andlogicplusrest)((\|\|)(?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&andlogicplusrestfacet)))?)

(?<andlogicplusrestfacet>(?&orplusrest)((&&)(?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&orplusrestfacet)))?)

(?<orplusrestfacet>(?&xorplusrest)((?!\|\|)(\|)(?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&xorplusrestfacet)))?)

(?<xorplusrestfacet>(?&andplusrest)((\^)(?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&andplusrestfacet)))?)

(?<andplusrestfacet>(?&eqplusrest)((?!&&)(&)(?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&eqplusrestfacet)))?)

(?<eqplusrestfacet>(?&relplusrest)((==|!=)(?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&relplusrestfacet)))?)

(?<relplusrestfacet>(?&shiftplusrest)(((?!<<)<|(?!>>)>|<=|>=)(?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&shiftplusrestfacet)))?)

(?<shiftplusrestfacet>(?&addmulplusrest)((<<|>>)(?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&addmulplusrestfacet)))?)
    
(?<addmulplusrestfacet>(?&mulop)(([\+\-])((?&primexprnoternaryfacet)(?!(?&mulopfacet))))?)

(?<mulopfacet>([\*\/\%])(?&primexprnoternaryfacet))

(?#end facets - follows the entry point)

)|(^(?&testentry))/xx;
                        
                        
print $&;
```